# How To Calculate Torrent Info Hash In VB6

Tags: vb6, bittorrent

I understand that you must calculate the SHA1 of the info dict in the torrent file, 
I am struggling Parsing the info dict, Do i Need to decode the bencoded info dict before calculating the sha1 hash??

How do I do it?

Answer (score 6):

The *info hash* is the SHA-1 hash of the *info dictionary* in bencoded format.

The torrent file contains a bencoded representation of the *meta info dictionary* which in turn contains the *info dictionary*.

You have to get the *info dictionary* part of the file in order to compute its hash. Assuming you have access to a bencode encoder and decoder you could:

- decode the whole file
- take the *info dictionary* part of it
- re-encode it for hashing.

In pseudo code:

```
metainfo = b_decode(contents_of("file.torrent"))
info = metainfo.getValue("info")
encoded_info = b_encode(info)
info_hash = sha1(encoded_info)
```

Comment: That would be wrong in some cases, because it would sort a unsorted info-dict and the agreed convention when a info-dict for some reason is unsorted, is to hash the info-dict raw as it is (unsorted). A more safe metod is described by Arvid here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749085/calculating-the-info-hash-of-a-torrent-file/19800109#19800109