# Sending HTTP Get to Bittorent tracker - Where's info_hash and peer_id?

Tags: java, bittorrent, tracker

I'm trying to send a HTTP get request to a tracker. But I don't know where the info_hash and peer_id are and I need them as parameters. According to bittorent specifications the info_hash is the metafile's info "info_hash: urlencoded 20-byte SHA1 hash of the value of the info key from the Metainfo file."and the peer_id "is allowed to be any value"

But when I put the properly URL encoded info key as the info_hash, and arbitrarly put something for the peer_id I get this error:
d14:failure reason20:Torrent unauthorisede

Can someone give me an example where the info_hash is in this file?

```
d8:announce40:http://tracker.the123ay.org/announce13:announce-listll40:http://tracker.th213bay.org/announceel35:udp://tracker.op123rrent.com:80el23:udp://tr123ker.ccc.de:80el29:udp://tracker.pawscbt.com:80el46:udp://tracker.tntvadse.scambioetico.org:2710ee7:comment46:Torrent downloaded from http://theadsde10:created by13:uTorrent/332013:creation datei1391719112e8:encoding5:UTF-84:infod13:file-durationli2462ei2474ee10:file-mediali0ei0ee5:filesld6:lengthi1443259870e4:pathl70:Casdasd7.Problemi.Di.Famiglia.ITA.720p.DLMux.h264-Noasdip.mkveed6:lengthi1461542146e4:pathl70:Chicaasdasx08.Una.Scelta.Difficile.ITA.720p.DLMux.h264-NovaRip.mkveee4:name48:Chicago.Fire.1x07-08.ITA.720p.DLMux.h264-NovaRip12:piece lengthi262144e6:pieces221620:
```

Using Java if it matters. Lmk if I need to give more info.

Comment: Still have no idea where the info_hash is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The info dictionary in your example starts at

> infod13:

You must determine the info data and calculate the SHA1 of the info data. After that you must to URL encode the SHA1.

> info_hash: urlencoded 20-byte SHA1 hash of the value of the info key from the Metainfo file. Note that the value will be a bencoded dictionary, given the definition of the info key above.

[description](https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification)

There is an example written in Qt which i think it might help you. (Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc_64/examples/network/torrent)
You can find it online here [qt torrent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-torrent.html)

Edit: Here is a good answer for what you are looking for [Calculating the info-hash of a torrent file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749085/calculating-the-info-hash-of-a-torrent-file)